# What does the word "dispensation" mean in sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in my book which was:

> Since 1969, the Congress party had started shedding its character as an umbrella party which accommodated leaders and workers of different ideological **dispensations** and viewpoints.

The word "dispensation" doesn't seem to make much sense to me in the context. Instead I think the word "inclination" would have made much more sense. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dispensation**, second meaning in [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dispensation):

> A political, religious, or social system prevailing at a particular time.

Examples:

- Scholarship is conveyed to a wider audience than under the old dispensation.
- So within these four parameters, one needs to crystallize the political dispensation that one would like to have in Afghanistan.

This meaning of *dispensation* was new to me too.